# How to calculate Grand Totals when using OVER (partition by ...) using Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am hoping the Oracle SQL experts out there can help with this.  I have a view that has the following columns:

```
MONTH (DATE)
JOB_GROUP (VARCHAR2)
PEOPLE (NUMBER)
```

My view currently looks like this:

```
SELECT
DISTINCT JOB_GROUP,
SUM(PEOPLE) OVER (PARTITION BY MONTH || JOB_GROUP) AS CURRENT_PEOPLE
SUM(PEOPLE) OVER (PARTITION BY MONTH || JOB_GROUP) / '100' AS RATIO
FROM MY_VIEW
WHERE MONTH = '01-DEC-2013'
ORDER BY RATIO DESC
```

The '100' comes from a hidden item on my apex page that pulls out the current month's Worker1, but for this example, I am just using the '100'.
The results of the query come out something like this.

```
JOB_GROUP CURRENT_PEOPLE RATIO 
WORKER1       100        1.0
WORKER2       80         0.8
WORKER3       50         0.5
```

The GRAND totals I am looking for are for CURRENT PEOPLE AND RATIO at the bottom of the query result.  I will be putting this into an APEX Classic report. In this example would be 230 and 2.3.  Since I am using the OVER (partition) method, I have not been able to use any sort of GROUP BY.

Appreciate any advice you may have..thank you

Comment: You shouldn't be using `(PARTITION BY MONTH || JOB_GROUP)`. For one you are subject to implicit type conversion and secondly it might yield wrong result because of that. Use both columns directly: `(PARTITION BY MONTH, JOB_GROUP)`. And don't use strings as numbers `'100'` is a string, not a number. Againg you are subject to implicit data type conversion. Your condition `MONTH = '01-DEC-2013'` is *also* subject to implicit data type conversion (and would simply throw an error on my computer). Use `to_date()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need analytic functions.  You can do this with regular aggregation:

```
SELECT JOB_GROUP,
       SUM(PEOPLE) AS CURRENT_PEOPLE
       SUM(PEOPLE) / '100' AS RATIO
FROM MY_VIEW
WHERE MONTH = '01-DEC-2013'
GROUP BY ROLLUP (OB_GROUP)
ORDER BY RATIO DESC;
```

The month isn't needed in the `group by`, because you are selecting only one month.