# How to divide by the result of another query

Tags: sql, oracle

This is a separate question based on a previous post:

[Link] [How to calculate Grand Totals when using OVER (partition by ...) using Oracle SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21381754/how-to-calculate-grand-totals-when-using-over-partition-by-using-oracle-sq)

I am using the following Oracle SQL query:

```
SELECT JOB_GROUP,
   SUM(PEOPLE) AS CURRENT_PEOPLE
   SUM(PEOPLE) / '100' AS RATIO
FROM MY_VIEW
WHERE MONTH = '01-DEC-2013'
GROUP BY ROLLUP (OB_GROUP)
ORDER BY RATIO DESC;
```

This query gives me an output like this..

```
JOB_GROUP    CURRENT_PEOPLE    RATIO
WORKER1     100                1.0
WORKER2     30                 .3
WORKER3     40                 .4
WORKER4     25                 .25
WORKER5     30                 .30
(NULL)      225                2.25
```

I need to be able to divide the sum of all of the ratios into the sum of the ratios where job_group = 'WORKER1', WORKER2, WORKER4. For Example, we can have 5 different job_groups, but I only need the sum of the ratio for 1, 2 and 4.  I suspect this is some type of subquery, but have not been able to get the right result yet.

The equation would look like sum(ratios) / sum(ratio) where worker, 1,2,4.  2.25 / (1.0 + .3 + .25) = .80

Thanks for any help you can provide,

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: What is the secret for adding a table into these boxes?  I've looked at the advanced help and could not find it.  I think you or someone edited by previous one and organized it nicely ;)  Thanks for your help.

Comment: . . Here is a reference . . . http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help.  In general, if you put four spaces at the beginning of a line, you get fixed width font in a shaded area, that looks good for both code and tables.

Comment: Hi...I added a table with data, I hope this makes it a little more clearer.  This a SQL fundamental I need to learn, so I am ver thankful.

Comment: Where are you getting the `0.80` value from; `2.25/1.55` is `1.45...`? And are you trying to get a single figure for this, or put the calculated value as an extra column for each row in your current result set? (I don't understand your current 'ratio' value anyway, but I don't think that's entirely relevant).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following uses an analytic function to get the number of worker1s:

```
select JOB_GROUP, CURRENT_PEOPLE,
       CURRENT_PEOPLE / sum(job_group = 'WORKER1' then CURRENT_PEOPLE end) over () as Ratio
from (SELECT JOB_GROUP,
             SUM(PEOPLE) AS CURRENT_PEOPLE
      FROM my_view
      WHERE MONTH = '01-DEC-2013'
      GROUP BY ROLLUP (JOB_GROUP)
     ) t
ORDER BY RATIO DESC;
```

Comment: This actually gives me the same result as the one above. If I were state the query in pseudocode it would sounds like this..what is the total ratio divided by the sum of the ratio's for workers 1, 2, and 4.  I suspect this can be accomplsihed by using a complex subquery.

Comment: I was playing with this query you provided and noticed if I changed it to group by job_group and add where job_group = 'WORKER1', then I get 1, no matter which worker you put in for the ''.

Comment: I created a subquery.  Combining analytic functions with aggregations can be confusing.